# how do you rename column in netezza which looks like - '?column?'?

Tags: alter-table, netezza, table-rename

How do you rename column in netezza table which looks like this '?COLUMN?'.
I have already tried alter table with above but did not work .

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference a column name that starts with a question mark you will need to enclose the column name in double quotation marks.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table test_table_1 ("?COLUMN?" BIGINT);
CREATE TABLE

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> \d test_table_1
             Table "TEST_TABLE_1"
 Attribute |  Type  | Modifier | Default Value
-----------+--------+----------+---------------
 ?COLUMN?  | BIGINT |          |
Distributed on random: (round-robin)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> alter table test_table_1 rename column "?COLUMN?" to SOMETHING_ELSE;
ALTER TABLE

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \d test_table_1
                Table "TEST_TABLE_1"
   Attribute    |  Type  | Modifier | Default Value
----------------+--------+----------+---------------
 SOMETHING_ELSE | BIGINT |          |
Distributed on random: (round-robin)
```

Comment: Thank You sir! Your response was really great ! This explains a lot :-) and it worked !! Just curious why round robin distribution ? does this help ? and \d command wont work on my sandbox what might be the reason?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as answered!